# Tasks taking longer over time in Apache Spark

Tags: performance, apache-spark, bigdata, cluster-computing, distributed-computing

I have a large dataset that I am trying to run with Apache Spark (around 5TB). I have noticed that when the job starts, it retrieves data really fast and the first stage of the job (a `map` transformation) gets done really fast.

However, after having processed around 500GB of data, that `map` transformation starts being slow and some of the tasks are taking several minutes or even hours to complete.

I am using 10 machines with 122 GB and 16CPUs and I am allocating all resources to each of the worker nodes. I thought about increasing the number of machines, but is there any other thing I could be missing?

I have tried with a small portion of my data set (30 GB) and it seemed to be working fine.

Comment: Just a wild guess, but could you try to use `mapPartitions` (in case there is some preparations for map phase, it should be faster).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that the stage gets completed locally in some nodes faster than in others. Driven from that observation, here is what I would try:

1. **Cache** the RDD that you process. Do not forget to unpersist it, when you don't need it anymore.
   [Understanding caching, persisting in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39196748/understanding-caching-persisting-in-spark/39199428#39199428).
2. Check if the **partitions** are *balanced*, which doesn't seem to be
   the case (that would explain why some local stages complete much
   earlier than others). Having balanced partitions is the holy grail
   in [distributed-computing](/questions/tagged/distributed-computing), isn't it? :)
   [How to balance my data across the partitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38799753/how-to-balance-my-data-across-the-partitions)
3. Reducing the communications costs, i.e. use *less workers* than you
   use, and see what happens. Of course that heavily depends on your
   application. You see, sometimes communication costs become so big,
   they dominate, so using less machines for example, speeds up the
   job. However, I would do that, only if steps 1 and 2 would not suffice.

Comment: This was the key: Check if the partitions are balanced. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without any more info it would seem that at some point of the computation your data gets spilled to the disk because there is no more space in memory.
It's just a guess, you should check your Spark UI.